# ¿Cómo hacer un servidor de hora con PHP en UDP?

Tags: php, c++, php7, tcpip

Necesito crear un servidor de hora en PHP y que se devuelva a través del protocolo UDP.

Mi código de server.php

```
<?php    
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montevideo');
$buf_size = 1024;
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:3127", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
do {
   $str = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf_size, 0, $peer); 
   $str = time();
   stream_socket_sendto($socket, $str, 0, $peer);    
 } while (true);
?>
```

Mi código de cliente

```
<?php
 $fp = stream_socket_client("udp://127.0.0.1:3127", $errno, $errstr);
 if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errno - $errstr<br />\n";
 } else {      
    fwrite($fp, "1 2 3");    
    echo fread($fp, 15);
    fclose($fp);
 }
?>
```

1- He configurado XAMPP para que acepte conexiones desde la misma red y en la PC servidor he creado reglas de entrada/salida para el puerto indicado.

2- Cuando hago localhost/client.php me devuelve la hora correctamente.

3- Cuando hago IP_del_server/client.php desde otra pc o móvil de la misma red me devuelve correctamente la hora.

4- Cuando intento usar un cliente (app de android o programa de windows), por ejemplo, Packet Sender, no me devuelve nada.

5- Cuando un colega intenta hacer un cliente en C++ no se puede conectar.

Creo que estoy mezclando conceptos, no sé como avanzar con esto, agradecería ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- He configurado XAMPP para que acepte conexiones desde la misma red y en la PC servidor he creado reglas de entrada/salida para el puerto indicado.

Perfecto

> 2- Cuando hago localhost/client.php me devuelve la hora correctamente.

Vamos bien, eso quiere decir que el servidor está operativo.

> 3- Cuando hago IP_del_server/client.php desde otra pc o móvil de la misma red me devuelve correctamente la hora.

Con esto vemos que el servidor es visible en la red local

> 4- Cuando intento usar un cliente (app de android o programa de windows), por ejemplo, Packet Sender, no me devuelve nada.

Aquí no aclaras si las conexiones son en la misma red local o desde Internet.

> 5- Cuando un colega intenta hacer un cliente en C++ no se puede conectar.

Tu servidor no es visible desde Internet.

En resumidas cuentas todo parece indicar que falta añadir una entrada en la tabla de enrutamiento de tu router para las peticiones realizadas por un puerto específico se redirijan a tu servidor.

Si lo que quieres es dejar el cliente como visible, puedes configurar el enrutamiento así:

```
TCP [IP_ROUTER]:5000 -> [IP_SERVIDOR]:80
```

En el router no uso el puerto 80 porque ese suele estar ya utilizado por el servidor web del propio router que permite configurarlo vía web.

Y si lo que quieres es dar visibilidad al servidor:

```
UDP [IP_ROUTER]:3127 -> [IP_SERVIDOR]:3127
```

Fíjate que los protocolos cambian en cada caso. El cliente utiliza externamente solo TCP, mientras que el servidor solo escucha peticiones UDP.

Para más información busca información sobre tablas NAT (Network Address Translation).

La IP de tu servidor solo es válida dentro de tu red local. Fuera de ese mundo esa IP o no existe o estará siendo utilizada por otro equipo. Lo que tienes que hacer es apuntar la IP pública de tu router y hacer que las peticiones externas se redirijan a esa IP.

Comment: Excelente explicación, lamento no haberlo aclarado antes. Yo quiero únicamente conexiones locales (no desde internet). Cuando me referí a mi colega intenté decir que estaba desarrollando un cliente en C++ para local (que tampoco funcionó).  Yo necesito que el protocolo sea UDP, así que añado únicamente la de UDP?

Comment: @Carlos si su cliente se va a conectar desde su casa entonces no va a ser una conexión local. Una conexión local solo se puede dar dentro de tu red local. Para conectarte desde fuera tienes que configurar las NAT del router y, posiblemente, configurar el antivirus/firewall

Comment: Ahora me he mezclado. Yo quiero que se conecten muchos dispositivos dentro de mi red local, no quiero que nadie se conecte desde fuera. En ese caso ¿debo configurar las NAT?

Comment: Eso es facil, dentro de tu red local no hace falta NAT.

Comment: Pero aun así conviene revisar el antivirus y el firewall para que no te den guerra

Comment: Las reglas ya están creadas para ese puerto (entrada y salida), pero no funciona. Creí que la solución era las NAT ¿cómo puedo hacerlo andar? (Lo que está hecho es lo que dice la pregunta? ¿Qué faltaría?

Comment: no me quedó claro como hacerlo para Local!! :(